# Trouble getting entries after a certain date

Tags: entries, datetime, filter

I have a bunch of entries with field eventStartDate and eventEndDate.

First I set the date

```
    {% set fwd = entry.eventStartDate|date_modify('+30 min')|date('c') %}
```

When I output the value of fwd, it is **2017-04-21T08:30:00-05:00**

So that's 4/21/2017 at 8:30 AM

Then I query the channel to get events after that date/time

```
{% set upcomingEvents = craft.entries
  .section('schedule')
  .order('eventStartDate asc')
  .eventStartDate('> ' ~ fwd )
  .limit(5)
  .status('live, pending')
%}
```

I get events on 4/21/17 starting at 8:00AM, not what I intended.

Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works - I double checked. I had a bug further down in my code.

```
{% set fwd = entry.eventStartDate|date_modify('+30 min')|date('c') %}

{% set upcomingEvents = craft.entries
  .section('schedule')
  .order('eventStartDate asc')
  .eventStartDate('> ' ~ fwd )
  .limit(5)
  .status('live, pending')
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an `and` in the date filter with a comma. When boiled down this is treaded as an array then converted to a SQL statement.

```
{% set upcomingEvents = craft.entries
  .section('schedule')
  .order('eventStartDate asc')
  .eventStartDate('and', '> ' ~ fwd )
  .limit(5)
  .status('live, pending')
%}
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting events starting before the value of {fwd}.

Comment: Try removing `|date('c')` from `fwd` eventStartDate.

Comment: Still not working - is there a way to see the full query the Craft is running?

Comment: If you have `devMode` turned on you can view in your JS console what craft is doing.

Comment: Got it - what am I looking for?

Comment: It will output a bunch of requests your looking for the SQL query that gives you the entries.

Comment: Yes - there are tons of queries. I tried filtering on eventStartDate but I get a huge swath of info.

Comment: Turns out I was displaying the wrong thing. The original code works! Where's the facepalm emoji?